# Reactjs - create manual webGl check since pixi is not using fallback

Tags: javascript, webgl, pixi.js

I'm currently using pixi.js to work with webGl, hence I need a fallback.

I already use the legacy version:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js-legacy'
```

But somehow it still throws an error when webGl is not supported saying I need to use the legacy version.

Since this is not working, I need to check for webGl somewhere else. I've already worked out the following code, which works in case webGl is disabled **but not if it's not supported**. How can I check for this as well?

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
return gl && gl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext;
```

Comment: Not sure why you need `gl instanceof WebGLRenderingContext`. Otherwise not sure what you're asking. that should be enough to test period.

Comment: It's enough to test whether webGl is disabled, but it's not working in case it's not supported

Answer (score 0):

The only way to check if the browser is so old it doesn't support WebGL is to check if `WebGLRenderingContext` exists. Note: If the browser is that old you can't use `const` as the browser will just see it that as a syntax error.

```
if (typeof WebGLRenderingContext === 'undefined') {
  // this browser doesn't even know what WebGL is
} else {
  var gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  if (!gl) {
     // webgl failed to initialize for any number of reasons
     // including it's turned off, the browser blacklisted the drivers,
     // it's out of memory, other.
  }
}
```

Checking for `experimental-webgl` basically means checking for buggy webgl so if you care about using a version of webgl with known bugs then you can add that in.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as the answer - however, testing it on lambdatest.com still returns `...please use pixi.js-legacy` for fallback since webGl is not supported. Somehow it detects when webGl is disabled in f.e. Firefox.